# Error reading file Libgdx RunTime Exception

Tags: java, android, libgdx

![enter image description here][1]I am encountering the following error in logcat. The app launches on the Android Emulator and then immediately crashes upon attempting to load  the splash screen. Specifically the logcat states that there it is:

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: assets/Images/Splash.png (Internal)
```

Below is the full logcat entry and an image of the file structure of my assets file structure. Any an all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 162
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets/Images/Splash.png
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.me.mygdxgame.Splash.show(Splash.java:66)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.me.mygdxgame.SimpleBike.create(SimpleBike.java:111)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: assets/Images/Splash.png (Internal)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:73)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:580)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:155)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:215)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     ... 11 more
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/Images/Splash.png
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:71)
04-28 15:47:04.105: E/AndroidRuntime(2527):     ... 15 more
04-28 15:47:04.165: I/AndroidInput(2527): sensor listener tear down
04-28 15:47:04.165: I/AndroidGraphics(2527): Managed meshes/app: { }
04-28 15:47:04.165: I/AndroidGraphics(2527): Managed textures/app: { }
04-28 15:47:04.165: I/AndroidGraphics(2527): Managed shaders/app: { }
04-28 15:47:04.165: I/AndroidGraphics(2527): Managed buffers/app: { }
04-28 15:47:08.845: I/Process(2527): Sending signal. PID: 2527 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can't upload image of assets file structure till I get 10 rep points on the site.

Comment: Check at this:Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/Images/Splash.png, the error is obvious.

Comment: That is what confuses me. The application works perfectly on desktop with the same assets folder and file paths. If I could upload an image of the assets file structure, I would. I should have an image "Splash.png" at that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more googling, I realized that the solution  was to change the file paths. Android paths are relative to the assets folder while the Desktop uses a path relative to the root folder. I just had to remove the "assets/" from the file paths, and it worked.